# Python - Multiprocessing slower than sequential?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm just getting aquanted with multiprocessing (as opposed to threading, this is supposed to leverage the multiple cores available). I'm using some dummy calculations to test speed:

```
def g(number):
    f = (math.factorial(number))
    f = f * 10
```

Then I try to call the function sequentially while measuring time:

```
start_time = time.time()  
g(10000)
g(2000)
g(3000)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This returns `--- 0.003850698471069336 seconds ---`
Now when I'm trying multiprocessing either via

```
start_time_ = time.time()
p = Pool(3)
p.map(g, [10000,2000,3000])
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time_))
```

or

```
start_time_1 = time.time()
pool = Pool(processes=3)
pool.map(g, [10000,2000,3000])
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time_1))
```

I get a much worse running time, `--- 0.0334630012512207 seconds ---` and `--- 0.6992270946502686 seconds ---`.

Why is running the 3 calculations on 3 different cores/processes result in a bigger calculation time? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, short computations execute slower in parallel because of the parallelization overhead, and the more processors, the slower. Try with something more substantial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414462/multicore-cpus-multithreading-and-context-switching

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you! Just adding a few zeroes to the paramters did the trick :) Btw. what's the difference between launching a `Pool` and mapping the functions and launching individual `Process`-es? Is one more efficient than the other? If I understand it correctly, `Pool` also assigns the calculations to individual processes/cores, right?